# Is it necessary to embed a 4D surface in 5D space?

Tags: general-relativity, geometry

Lets consider the line element:

$$ds^2=dr^2+r^2[d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2]$$

There are three variables r,theta and phi.
If we use a surface constraint like r=constant the number of
independent variables is reduced by one--now we have two independent
variables.These surfaces[corresponding to r=const] may be embedded in
a three dimensional space.

Now lets consider Schwarzschild's metric:

$$ds^2=(1-2m/r)dt^2 - (1-2m/r)^{-1} dr^2  - r^2[d \theta^2+\sin^2 \theta d\phi^2]$$

If we use a surface constraint[for example: t=constant] we have three
independent variables.The resulting time slices are three dimensional surfaces which are naturally embedded in a 4D space.

The General Relativity metric  has four variables: one relating to
time and three relating to the spatial coordinates.Any surface
constraint would reduce the number of variables to three.

In fact any arbitrary spacetime curve[world-line] may be made to lie
on a 3D- Surface obtained by applying some suitable constraint on 4D
space.The constraint may not be a simple one like t= constant or r= constant. It may be of a complicated nature.
For the purpose of embedding in GR a 4D space seems to be sufficient.

Queries:

1. Is it essential the we should consider a 4D surface embedded in 5D space to understand or interpret GR?
2. It appears that the curve[4D path] is more important than the surface on which it is lying since the same curve may be made to lie on several distinct surfaces at the same time[you may extend this to the case of  4D surf embedded in 5D space].Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: IMO, Christophs answer is quite complete and should close the question

Comment: A tangent vector of finite length protrudes out of the manifold.The null vector is parallel to and perpendicular to itself .It is perpendicular to the manifold .  It protrudes out of the surface--into what?

Answer (score 3):

Any enclosing space is outside of the problem domain of GR: All results can be obtained from within the space-time. Physically, it makes no sense to talk about an enclosing space which has no impact whatsoever on measurements. In particular, even though we say space-time is curved, the question *Where does it curve to?* makes no sense in the framework of GR.

Also, 5 dimensions are not enough to contain arbitrary 4-dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifolds of index 1 if you want to preserve the metric. Quoting [C. J. S. Clarke, On the Global Isometric Embedding of Pseudo-Riemannian Manifolds](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2416482):

> The space-time of general relativity can be embedded isometrically in $E^{2,q+2}$ (pseudo-Euclidean space of signature $q-2$) where $q=46$ or $q=87$ for compact or non-compact space-time, respectively.

However, the result is only valid for finite $k$ and not $C^\infty$.

Comment: I suppose you need a second time in order to deal with closed timelike loops. If you use time-oriented spacetimes the dimension should go down a lot. Also, these types of results tend to not be at all close to optimal.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not essential to consider a surface to be embedded in a higher-dimensional space. In fact the embedding is pretty much irrelevant. GR is based on differential geometry, and part of the reason differential geometry was developed the way it was is that it allows you to analyze surfaces without having to consider their embeddings in higher-dimensional spaces. You can calculate the geodesics or whatever else you want using only properties that can be measured from "within" the space.

Comment: But we always think in terms of a space-time surface.The same 4D path relevant to the motion of a particle, may be included in several[distinct] surfaces. The path seems to be more important than the surface including it.How do you explain that?

Comment: @Anamitra Palit: Nobody thinks in terms of a "space-time surface". The space time is not sitting in a bigger space time, it's all there is.

Comment: In your language (where "path" is the thing that is embedded and "surface" is the thing that it is embedded in), no, we do _not_ always think in terms of a spacetime surface. As I was saying, the surface is completely irrelevant. There doesn't even have to be a surface. Not all 4D paths are embeddable in 5D surfaces.

Comment: In fact, you have to work very hard if you want to represent your spacetime as an embedded surface in a flat space.  "Hard" in the sense that the flat space has, in general, to have very large number of dimensions.  I can't remember the dimensionality for embedding 3+1 Lorentzian spacetimes, but the calculations are related to the [Whitney Embedding Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem).  Does anyone know the number ? - something not much less than 100 rings a bell.....

Comment: @twistor59: for 4-dimensional Riemannian manifolds, the upper bounds of the dimension of the enclosing Euclidean space are 46 for compact manifolds and 230 for non-compact manifolds by Nash's embedding theorem; similarly, any pseudo-Riemannian manifold can be embedded into a pseudo-Euclidean space, but I don't know the specific bounds; I'd be surprised if they were smaller than the one's for the Riemannian case, though...

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks - the numbers are indeed pretty big !  A relevant paper for the Lorentzian case is Clarke, C. J. S., "On the global isometric embedding of pseudo-Riemannian manifolds," Proc. Roy. Soc. A314 (1970) 417-428, but unfortunately it's not free access...

Comment: @twistor59: according to my google-fu ( http://www.physicsforums.com/showpost.php?s=e6a2b1cf58923a18bd4b2d192a265d12&p=2064674&postcount=5 ), there's an upper bound of 90=87+3 (spacelike + timelike) dimensions for 3+1 pseudo-Riemannian manifolds

Comment: @Christoph: That sounds familiar.  Perhaps that's where I remembered it from.  I wonder if that number is sufficient for all Lorentz sig spacetimes, or only compact ones...

Comment: @twistor59: see my new answer; the cited paper actually gives the bound as 89, not 90...

Comment: The manifold itself is a surface,a space-time surface in the context of GR----and we use small portions of this surface to create local charts. Doing away with the surface itself seems like doing away with the manifold together with the local charts on it.

Comment: Instead of considering a surface[manifold] we consider the space as an n+1-dimensional volume.The same space R(n+1) may be loaded with the Euclidean metric,or any other type of metric that best suits the physical situation.The coordinate description should be the same for all physical situations[metrics] but the physical separations would be different.Suppose we start with a surface z-k(const) in flat space,the spatial aspect being considered.If the metric changes, the distances of different points on z=k from the x-y coordinate-plane would change leading to the formation of a curved surface!

Comment: The basic idea behind local-charting is to apply Special-Relativity. And we take small open sets on the manifold[for correspondence with the tangent plane,$E_n$] so that $ds^2$ does not change appreciably. But in the projective transformations [described in the previous comment in a suggestive way] we can always allow changes in $ds^2$ and go about our work *if the laws of physics are preserved* in all distinct types of manifolds.

Comment: On the Preservation of Laws[wrt the manifold/surface picture]: We start with a simple analogy.We often break up a curved line into infinitesimally pieces and replace each with a small straight line segment.No matter how small a piece we take the equation of a curved line is *never* identical with that of a straight line. But the first order derivatives are same at the point of contact.This fact is not valid for higher order derivatives.Now let’s consider a tensor $(A_t,A_r,A_\theta,A_\phi)$,the coordinate values $A_i$ do not change with different manifolds.

Comment: (in continuation)At the point of contact with the tangent plane $A_i$ as well as the first order derivatives of $g_{\mu\nu}$ should be identical for both manifolds.Any law involving $A_i$ and the first order derivatives $g_{\mu\nu}$ should be preserved. Involvement of higher orderivatives could cause problems.

Comment: In the projective geometry picture a law may/may not be preserved in the new space. But if this space is flat spacetime the law might be of a simpler form—--we have a convenient global workspace. In any case we if the law involves $A_i$ and its first order derivatives of $g_{\mu\nu}$ the law should be identical on flat spacetime[if the covariant form is used].If the law changes in the new workspace we can always go back to the old one by using the reverse transformations[projective].

Comment: Any chance you could take this to [chat]? The comments aren't really meant for extended discussion.

Comment: The ordinary derivative is not the rate measurer in curved spacetime.Rather the corvariant derivative is the correct rate measurer in view of parallel-transport.My previous comments may be reviewed/revised in the context of this fact and the information in the following link:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88762/how-do-you-define-coordinate-transformation [How do you Define "Coordinate Transformation"?]